# Delay on lodash throttle on wheel event. Leading option = true not working?

Tags: lodash, parallax, gsap, mousewheel, throttling

Throttle is working, but there's still a delay in execution even when the leading option is set to true.  Can't tell if this is a bug with _.throttle, if I'm using it incorrectly, or if the delay is a performance issue in my gsap.  Any ideas?

https://codepen.io/TPDBrendan/pen/xxRyWyz

```
window.addEventListener(
  "wheel",
  _.throttle(handleWheel, duration * 1000, { leading: true, trailing: false })
);
```

Comment: What delay are you talking about? It seems to respond very quickly to my mousewheel

Comment: @ZachSaucier I'm trying to emulate the functionality on https://circle.squarespace.com/, which animates pretty much instantaneously.  I think the delay is dependent on when the wheel event fires in the throttle window, which is why I'm stumped by leading:true isn't doing anything.

I added arrow key functionality to this pen - you can see with the arrow keys how it should look when the slides animate without a delay.